# How to add additional option and query element in JSON Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ace-editor

1. How to add custom element in JSONEditor (https://www.jsoneditoronline.org) popup (Attach image of JSONEditor with popup)
2. How to add a new custom element (say "Create or Edit action in the drop-down") displayed only for a certain element in the JSON (similar to element array in the picture)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I haven't been able to spot any documentation in this regard in the JSON editor

Comment: Were you able to do it?